# How to get from a specific TFS folder in Visual Studio directly to the same folder in TFS web portal?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-express, team-explorer, tfs-web-access

We use TFS primarily for documentation etc. Therefore, we have a workflow of managing the files in Visual Studio (Express) 2015 (e.g. check in) and then sending the web links (extracted from the web portal) per email for others to read.

There is a link to the web portal in the home view of the Team Explorer of Visual Studio (Express) 2015, but it takes us to a front page of the web portal and we have to navigate through the path once again.

Thus my question: Is there a way to directly open the TFS web portal from Visual Studio (Express) 2015 with the same path that is selected in Visual Studio? Or is there no alternative to navigating twice through the paths every time? I have consulted the TFS documentation, but I haven't found anything helpful yet.

I would appreciate any kind of help provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no this function for now. You may have to write a custom VS extension to achieve this or **ask a feature request** in [UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services), TFS Admin will kindly review it.